# displaying jp2 images stored in mysql database into web page

Tags: php

Here 'm trying for displaying jp2 image in a web page.

But I'm not able to converting it.

The simple code is like this

```
          <html>

              <body>
              <table><tr><td>
              <?php
               echo ' PHOT:'.getPhotoFromMysqlDB();
               ?>
               </td></tr></table>
            </body>
            </html?>
```

**getPhotoFromMysqlDB() will return jp2 image.**

**If i run above example the web page displaying junk like "bytecode" **

Comment: are u trying this <img src="photo" >

Comment: share with us what print echo statement ?

Comment: JP2 image display in a web page

Comment: i am not understand what is JP2 and  junk bytecode. if it is image name than look path where actualy image is store. it means give image name with fullpath in here <img src="image path/ image name" > i hope u understand what i what to say

Answer (score 0):

use below code:

```
    <html>
      <body>
      <table>
          <tr><td>
                <img src="<?php  echo ' PHOT:'.getPhotoFromMysqlDB();?>">
       </td></tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: what did u get in echo?

Comment: what did u say? not clear you store image then how get byte code  jp2 image?